# Downvoting answers to questions asked like "do my homework"

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

Do answers to questions that didn't come with attempts, and are just like "do my homework", deserve a downvote?

Example:

[Filtering out numbers that have sequential- consecutive or non-consecutive digits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/470741/72456)

In just 5 minutes after I posted my answer there I got 3 down votes without any comments, so at first I thought it was maybe because I didn't include an explanation of what my answer does while I was on my way to adding explanation but I'm quite slow since my native language is not English.

After I finished editing, I only got one down-vote reverted but still 2 were there and I really don't know why people voted down, except maybe it was inappropriate in their opinion to answer to the question which is asked as **"do my homework"**.

If this is the reason of downvoting my answer or another answer there, then what is community saying for this kind of questions? Should we really  not answer these questions? If yes then more than half of Q&A in this site are just asked for "do my homework" and we should downvote all then?

Comment: People down vote for a variety of reasons.   Part of the problem that you’ve observed is that they downvote and don’t come back to see whether you’ve improved the post: see [Concept of “conditional” downvotes?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8623/354511)

Comment: I'm not sure of the timing of the votes, and whether any occurred before your first edit. I wouldn't have downvoted the first version, but I tend to not upvote code-only answers that lack explanations. I prefer clear, didactic explanations, which can teach questioners in the long term.

Comment: More examples: *[Add new line after third comma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474882)*, *[Collecting specific genome data from a file and collect it in the same title](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474268)*, and *[Multiply digits within a number with each other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474021)* (from 3 consecutive days).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Both questions and answers should be voted on purely on their own merits.

If someone writes a comprehensive answer to a marginally asked question, it's not appropriate to downvote such an answer, IMO. In all cases, the question should be edited if possible to improve it as much as possible and the answer should be voted on based on their own independent quality.

There is even a badge to reinforce this point called the "reversal" which is awarded when someone is able to provide a solid answer to a poor question.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/reversal

There's only ever been 2 awarded on this site 8-). I attribute this to our sites willingness to edit poorly written questions so that they never reach the -5 threshold required to trigger this.

Comment: I've rarely seen questions with lower than -3 on U&L. I figured that was because it wasn't worth downvoting such a question any lower (they're often from low scoring / new users anyway).

Comment: @roaima - same here, we as a community are pretty consistent about this, we either vote things up strongly or down to the ~-3 level, or close/delete it. It's one of the reasons I prefer this site to some of the other SE's.

Answer (score 13):

The description for answer vote reads "*this answer is/is not useful*". If the question isn't great but the answer is clearly useful, the answer should not be down voted.

If the question is too vague, it becomes hard to write useful and meaningful answers. If you find an answer to such question to be not useful, it is the reason down vote is there.